# Gain access to data of disabled iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

My iPad Pro with iOS version 11++ has been disabled and I only get a screen : "iPad is disabled. Connect to iTunes.". It need to be restored in order to function again properly but all data would be erased. How can I access the data while it is disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a computer you trusted before with your Apple ID logged in? If this is the case, there's little possibility you might be able to get to your data. I have just blocked my iPhone and tried with iTunes, still could get to all data stored.

I know the answer is probably not, yet may be you previously have done a back up of this device? You'd just restore the device from it with all contents.